# How to correctly print address of a variable in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, ollydbg

i'm trying to understand how c or c++ structures ar stored in memory.

i wrote a small program in c++ and i compiled and ran it into a debugger. i used printf with %p and &variable to print the address but the address printed out and the actual address in memory are completely different. in fact the printed address is not even valid.

any idea how can i correctly print the real address of a variable or structure?

thanks

here is the source code of the program i wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define XXX __asm__("nop");

int main(){
    XXX;
    XXX;
    const char *short_string = "this is a short string";
    const wchar_t *long_string = L"this is a long string";
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int c = a + b;
    int *pointer_to_a = &a;

    std::cout << "the address of short_string is: " << &short_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the address of long_string is: " << &long_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the address of a is: " << &a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the address of a is: " << pointer_to_a << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << "+" << b << "=" << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    XXX;
    XXX;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output from the compiled program:
[image: compiled program]

this is the location in memory of the variables:
[image: debugger output]

Comment: You seem to be making the common newbie mistake of confusing the address of the pointer variable with the address the variable is pointing at. Try comparing `cout << &ptr;` with `cout << (void*)ptr;`. All variables have addresses (the address they are stored at) but in addition pointer variables have the address being pointed at. It's a source of much confusion.

Comment: &short_string is different then what you think it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To print the location of your string, you need to:
std::cout << (void*)short_string;

In your example you write the address of where is your local variable, which is on the stack